# Script for display wrapper class Account list of records?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Hi i am trying to write script for display list of records from wrapper class.

```
 @remoteaction
    public static wrappercls getaccounts(){
        string account = 'select id,name,accountnumber from account';
        listacc = database.query(account);
        count = listacc.size();
        system.debug('#####'+count);
        wrappercls wra = new wrappercls(count,listacc);
        return wra;
    }

    public class wrappercls{
        public integer count11;
        public list<account> account;

        public wrappercls(integer count11,list<account> account){
            this.count11 = count11;
            this.account = account;
        }
    }
```

This class returns list of account records and record count parameter.Need to display these records in page.Is it possible if possible Please help me on this..

Script

```
<script>
  function getallaccounts(){
    exremote.getaccounts(
        function(result,event){
            if(event.status){

            }
            else {

            }
       },{escape:true}
    );
}
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the response in your `result` variable. Now it's up to you and your creativity how you're going to display the records on the page. You will need to write some JavaScript though. Here is a starting point and one way of creating a table dynamically and shoving it inside an existing DIV on your page:

```
<div id="accountList" />

<script>
  function getallaccounts(){
    exremote.getaccounts(
        function(result,event){
            if(event.status){
                var html = '<table>';

                for (var i = 0; i < result.count11; i++)
                {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + result.account[i].Id + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + result.account[i].name + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + result.account[i].accountnumber + '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                }

                html += '</table>';
                document.getElementById('accountList').innerHTML = html;
            }
            else {

            }
       },{escape:true}
    );
}
</script>
```